# Can not display username when using Cordova

Tags: php, cordova

My code works perfectly fine when I use it locally and can access the server (using XAMPP).
However, when I run it through Cordova I can not display the username. The username is saved as a $_SESSION variable in the login.php file when the user logs in, but gets the error message Warning: Undefined array key "username".
The postings of the web application are shown, so I know I can access the server when using Cordova as well.

In the HTML file, the displayUserName() function is called onload which sends a request to displayName.php.

The displayAllPosts() function works.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

session_start();
// Establish connection to database
include("connection.php");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');



// Setting the vairables for the email and password.
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//SQL query for retrieving the username and userID where email is 
//current email and password is current password.
$sql_user = "SELECT username, user_id FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";

// Store the result from the sql query
$result_user = mysqli_query($link, $sql_user) or die (mysqli_connect($link));

// Check if there is data returned.
// If num of rows returned is 0, then there is no registered user with
// the provided email and password
if ((mysqli_num_rows($result_user) < 1)){
    echo 1;
}

// Otherwise the username and password has been found in the db.
else{
    //Saving the result as an associative array called row.
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_user);
    //Setting the session variable for username and user id. 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    
    echo 2;
}
// Close the connection to the db
$conn->close();
```

?>

```
<?php

session_start();
// Establish connection to database
include("connection.php");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

// Session vaiable for username when logged in. 
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

?>

```js
function displayUserName() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://MY_IP_ADDRESS/test/server/displayName.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function (userdata) {
            // Not found in db. Provide feedback to user.
            if (!userdata) {
                document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = "No text";
            }
            //Successfully found in db and username will be displayed.
            if (userdata) {
                document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = "Inloggad: " + userdata;
            }
        }
    });
};

function displayAllPosts() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://MY_IP_ADDRESS/test/server/displayAllPosts.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //Check if there is data. 
            if (!data) {
                document.getElementById("displayAllPosts").innerHTML = "no data.";
            }
            else {
                //Create a constant to determine in which element the postings 
                //should be displayed. This element will be the parent element.
                const allPosts = document.getElementById('displayAllPosts');
```

```html
<body onload="displayUserName(); displayAllPosts()">
    <!-- Here is the logo -->
    <div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <img src="img/hth.png" alt="Here to help logo" width="300" height="100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Display the username that is logged in-->
    <div class="container pt-3 pb-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end" id="displayname">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display the name of the section-->
    <div class="container pt-1 pb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h1>Inlägg</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Div to display all posts-->
    <div class="container pt-1 pb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="event-wrapper" id="displayAllPosts">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The username is stored upon log in. When I run my code locally it displays the username.
[Username displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qk0b.jpg)

However, when I use Cordova an warning message is displayed.
[Warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMsRC.jpg)

Comment: I'd guess it's probably not got a session cookie active to show the server that there's a browser session to link to.

Comment: I am unsure how to activate it?

Comment: check weather your username is stored at login time or not .. try var_dump username at loigin page.